# Partial Postback with JQUERY

Tags: jquery, postback, partial

Issue : I need a partial post back when my JQUERY finishes the service call and data return back to my aspx page.

Background : I have a web page(aspx), on which we have one server side button control.
If i click on button one JQUERY dilogue  will open.This popup give some search functionality (search functionality implemented through MVC and search results returned from a service).If i select my matching result it will populate the selected data on to respective textboxes on my web page and JQUERY dialogue will get closed.So here after JQUERY dialogue gets closed i need a partail post back of my webpage.In my web page  5 udatepanel are there.

Below is the sample code of my JQUERY functionality

```
var url = "../SearchLookup/GetEntityDetail";
    $.post(url, { Id: referenceId }, function (data) {
        if (data.ErrorId != "TxnErr1") {
           //this function will populate the selected information on to the web page
            SearchCallBack(data);
            $("#SearchDialog").dialog("close");
           //here i want to do partial post back of my web page
        }
```

Please suggest me on this.